# Flash туториалы

Tags: flash, actionscript

Здраствуйте!
Помогите, пожалуйста, найти хорошие видеоуроки по Flash и ActionScript 3 на русском языке.

Answer (score 1):

Очень хороший ресурс http://easyflash.org/

На сайте имеются очень хорошие уроки и по flash и по actionscript. 
Причем есть, как платные, так и не платные уроки (их будет достаточно, чтобы научиться). Предлагаемые уроки являются понятными и интересными

Помимо всего, подписавшись на рассылку, Вы будете получать на почту новые видео-уроки.